# How Uber GPS system works?

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, uber-api, android-gps

I'm new to GPS and trying to understand how UBER actually tract N no of cars locations and send relevant data to users
Couple of questions I have
1) Does phone installed in UBER cabs need SIM cards and mobile data active? if yes, can we achieve the same without using mobile data?
2) How do they track and filter cars in areas as per users search along with type of cars

Please explain in as detail considering I'm a lay man full functionality starting from user search request send received at DB to how DB gets cars locations to filtering and sending back that data to user thank you

Comment: THis question is way too broad.  The purpose of this site is to help people with a particular programming problem, not to design your app from the top down.

Comment: Hi @GabeSechan I was not excepting end to end programming code here   I was excepting an theoretical explanation oh how a server will know particular cars location. may be its way too broad but will you be able answer my 2 questions at least in theoretical way?